# Panel Data - sum by group and create new variable

Tags: r, sum, panel-data

I know there are already a lot of questions on "sum by group" posed, however, I do not get solved my problem. Here is it:

df1 is my simplified data set

```
> df1 = data.table( Year = c(2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010),
                  ID = c(1621, 1621, 1628,1628,3101, 3101,3105,3105,1621, 1621, 1628,1628 ), 
                  category= c("0910","0910","0911","0913", "0914", "0910","0910","0911","1014","1012","1011","1013"),
                  var1 = c(60,70, 400,300,15,20, 200,150,61,71,401,301) )
```

df2 is the desired result (see var2):

```
> df2 = data.table( Year = c(2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010),
                  ID = c(1621, 1621, 1628,1628,3101, 3101,3105,3105,1621, 1621, 1628,1628 ), 
                  category= c("0910","0910","0911","0913", "0914", "0910","0910","0911","1014","1012","1011","1013"),
                  var1 = c(60,70, 400,300,15,20, 200,150,61,71,401,301), 
                  var2= c(130,130,700,700,35,35,350,350,132,132,702,702) )
```

So I would like to calculate the sums of `var1` grouped by `ID` and the first two integers of `category`

So if the first two integers of the variable category is 09 (or 10 and so on), then assign to `var2` the sum by group `ID` and the first two integers of `category`. Then, equal IDs in the same category should get assigned the same sum.

I tried to achiev that by

```
> df1$var2 = rep(NA, rep(length(df1$ID)))
df1$var2 = ifelse(substr(df1$category,1,2)=="09", by(df1[Year==2009,]$var1, df1[Year==2009,]$ID,sum), df1$var2)
df1$Var2 = ifelse(substr(df1$category,1,2)=="10", by(df1[Year==2010,]$var1, df1[Year==2010,]$ID,sum), df1$var1)
```

But here the sums are not assigned to the correct item.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Please take some time to format your code.

Comment: You can do that by highlighting your code and Ctrl + K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = data.frame( Year = c(2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2009,2010,2010,2010,2010),
                  ID = c(1621, 1621, 1628,1628,3101, 3101,3105,3105,1621, 1621, 1628,1628 ), 
                  category= c("0910",NA,"0911","0913", "0914", "0910","0910",NA,"1014","1012",NA,"1013"),
                  var1 = c(60,70, 400,300,15,20, 200,150,61,71,401,301) )
```

I added NA values in OP's original dataframe to reflect the full specification he desired.

```
df1$category_sub = substr(df1$category, 1, 2)
df1_aggre = aggregate(var1 ~ ID + category_sub, data = df1, sum)
names(df1_aggre)[3] = "var2"

df2 = merge(df1, df1_aggre, all=TRUE)
df2[order(df2$Year),]
```

Result:

```
> df2[order(df2$Year),]
     ID category_sub Year category var1 var2
1  1621           09 2009     0910   60   60
4  1621         <NA> 2009     <NA>   70   NA
5  1628           09 2009     0911  400  700
6  1628           09 2009     0913  300  700
9  3101           09 2009     0914   15   35
10 3101           09 2009     0910   20   35
11 3105           09 2009     0910  200  200
12 3105         <NA> 2009     <NA>  150   NA
2  1621           10 2010     1014   61  132
3  1621           10 2010     1012   71  132
7  1628           10 2010     1013  301  301
8  1628         <NA> 2010     <NA>  401   NA
```

I first extracted the first two integers from `category` and grouped `var1` by `ID` and `category_sub`. I then renamed `var1` to `var2` and merged `df1` and `df1_aggre` by `ID` and `category_sub` with `all=TRUE` option. This specifies a full outer join. The resulting dataframe was unsorted, so I sorted `df2` by `Year` to get the desired result.

Comment: How would you deal with the problem if you necessarily need to the take the first to integers of categroy ( substr(category,1,2) and not Year?

Comment: @Enrico do you mean extract first two integers from `category` and group by those instead?

Comment: This is because of some other reasons which I did not included here: Some IDs have a missing value in category, and these should be excluded from the sum. Those gaps I did not indlude to the simplified data set df1.

Comment: ! Yes, exactly!

Comment: @Enrico I updated my answer to reflect what you wanted